# iOS 7 complete UINavigationBar transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to make this transparency look in a ViewControllers Navigation bar:

**WANTED:**

[image]

Till now i got only this done. The bar is not losing its color:

[image]

**Used code:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: what app is that with kany west?

Comment: It's just a sample app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

And in Swift

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Comment: This is the better solution. No need to create images or render. A new image is a clear image - precisely what was required.

Comment: Your right, it worked. Up voted both answers because they do the same. Your one is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Please try these codes:

```
//set the nav bar complete transparent 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//remove the bottom show from nav bar
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];


- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: i m on the way atm, ill check it at home!

Comment: You seem to be missing a definition for -imageWithColor:.